# Why would DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL Fail when i have the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE Role?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, permissions

I am trying to get the **DDL** using `METADATA_DBMS.GET_DDL` for an object in a database, and I get the following error:

```
ORA-31603: object "MY_PACKAGE" of type PACKAGE not found in schema "S1"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 3149
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4787
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

This is how I am calling the `METADATA_DBMS.GET_DDL`:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (object_type, object_name, owner)
       FROM dba_objects
       WHERE OBJECT_ID = (select OBJECT_ID from dba_objects where object_name ='MY_PACKAGE' and object_type = 'PACKAGE' and owner = 'S1')
```

I wrote it with the subquery to make sure the object exists in the schema S1. I am certain `S1.MY_PACKAGE` exists, I can even look at it in TOAD Schema Browser.

I have the following roles granted:

```
select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS 

USERNAME  GRANTED_ROLE         ADMIN_OPTION  DEFAULT_ROLE  OS_GRANTED
MYUSER    CONNECT              NO              YES          NO
MYUSER    DBA                  NO              YES          NO
MYUSER    SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE  NO              YES          NO
```

I had `DBA Role` first, and since it was throwing that error I granted myself `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`.

I checked against another Database Instance where the query works and I have the same roles, what else do I need to make `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` work?

Both databases are a clone from the same source database, and I later got the privileges granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was some issue with TOAD. I opened TOAD after they granted me `DBA Role`, yet it was like it did not take effect.

I could query the `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` table and see I had the role, I could `GRANT` myself the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE, but when I called `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` it did not work.

Since I had open TOAD after the access had been granted, I didn't think that was the issue. At last, as a desperate measure, I tried closing everything and Opening it again and it worked.

I was going to delete this question, but I guess it could be useful for someone else in the future.